# TFS Suspend State Tracking

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I would like our team, to be able, to communicate to others easily, if they have suspended their work with a given reason.

So I would like to have the WIT's with an additional state named "suspended" and an given comment.

What we now would like to achieve, is that the newly added suspended state is set, when we press the suspend work button.

How to add an additional state is clearly documented on the msdn, but is there any possible way, to achieve the above mentioned behaviour, where we do not have to switch to all the associated WIT's and set the state manually?

Comment: "where we do not have to switch to all the associated WIT's and set the state manually?" is not that clear to me. You ask if there is a way to change in bulk a work item type (or more than one) in multiple projects and collections?

Comment: In Visual Studio TeamExplorer you have the Tab "My Work". There you see a list of all associated Tasks. Then you select X Tasks and click Start. Then the tasks are marked as InProgress. Also you have an additional Button named Suspend work. A shelveset and mroe is automatically created for the Work and you can focus on sth else. What we want is, that when someone suspends his work because of X, that the state of all associated wit's is set to suspended and if possible with a comment.

Comment: Please edit your question then: now I see clearly that you refer to a VS feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement can't be achieved by default. You would need to customize your own add-in in VS.